# How to decrypt the encrypted file system data file dump from blackberry using CFP

Tags: image, blackberry, filesystems

I use a official tool called CFP(RIM Wireless Device Command-Line Programmer Version 3.9.0.49) dump a blackberry file system data into a file, but this blackberry is a secure device, so the file has been encrypted. (cmd: CFP -u CSAVEFS blackberry_dump.bin)

how could i decrypt this file?

FILE FORMAT: "...REDFEDMP[SIZE][ENCRYPTED DATA]EKEY[KEYLEN][KEY]"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you wont find a retail blackberry that isn't a secure device (this feature is for developers).